# res.end() not closing the script execution in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

return res.end() not closing script execution.
Initially it renders the form and when i submit it executes the code block below closing brace of if statement.
I think execution should have ended on the line return res.end().

```
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const url = req.url;
  if (url === "/") {
    res.write("<html>");
    res.write("<head><title>FORM</title></head>");
    res.write(
      "<body><form action='/message' method='POST'><input type='text' name='message' /><button>Send</button></from></body>"
    );
    res.write("</html>");
    return res.end();
  }
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
  res.write("<html>");
  res.write("<head><title>APP</title></head>");
  res.write("<body><h1>Demo APP</h1></body>");
  res.write("</html>");
});

server.listen(4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `console.log(req.url)` to the start of your request handler.  You will find that:

```
return res.end();
```

does indeed stop the execution of that particular request by returning from the request handler callback.

But, you are most likely then getting another incoming http request, probably for `favicon.ico`.  In general you should never have code in a request handler that pays zero attention to what resource is being requested unless it's sending back an error like a 404 because there are lots of requests that can potentially be made to your http server for somewhat standard resources sucn as `robots.txt`, `favicon.ico`, `sitemap.xml` and so on and you shouldn't be answering for those requests unless you are sending the appropriate data for those requests.

Comment: @faheemkhan - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put the remainder of the code in ELSE block to ensure it is run only when URL!=="/"

Comment: That won't really make a difference here.  The `return` does indeed stop the rest of that particular request from executing.  The likely issue here is that there are other incoming http requests for other resources that are executing the rest of the code.

Comment: My bad, I have missed the RETURN part.